# requiring NPM module from npm cache

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, yarnpkg

On OSX/*nix the `~/.npm` directory holds the npm cache, which seems to be structured like this:

```
foo/
  0.1.2/
  1.0.01/
  1.3.34/
  2.0.1/
bar/
  0.3.8/
  2.1.1/
baz/
  3.2.1/
  4.1.7/
```

I am wondering if we could require modules directory from this directory. I am sure this completely goes against NPM philosophy, but just wondering what the easiest way would be to go about it.

I imagine changing NODE_PATH to use the ~/.npm directory would be a possibility, but the ~/.npm directory seems to have a different structure, so not sure if `require()` can work with that.

We see new package managers like `Yarn` who are trying to improve `NPM`. In my opinion, I am still confused to this day why NPM doesn't just use the .npm cache to reference dependencies (why rewrite them locally in the project directory?), but maybe someone can address that.

My end goal is find a way to get huge dependencies like Babel, Istanbul in one location on disk and reference that location everywhere (at least for the same user). With tools like NVM, global module location (npm root -g) changes, so best to use something in the $HOME directory, and since .npm cache is already there it offers a possibility.

Besides manipulating NODE_PATH to work with the ~/.npm directory (I just tried it and the directory structure of ~/.npm seems to preclude this), another solution might be to use npm programmatically.

Something like this:

```
const npm = require('npm');
npm.load({
    loaded: false
}, function (err) {
  // catch errors
  npm.commands.install(['babel','istanbul'], function (er, data) {
    // log the error or data
  });
  npm.on('log', function (message) {
    // log the progress of the installation
    console.log(message);
  });
});
```

Comment: If you have a `projects/` directory, you can install things in that directory's `node_modules` and every subdirectory which contains a `require()` to a module in the parent's `node_modules` *should* be able to access it (see [the Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)). Is this close to what you need, or do you specifically want the cache to be the source?

Answer (score 1):

I have been asking myself the same question. If I have a `package.json` with all the dependencies I need and all the dev-dependencies I need then why would I want to have to do it again and confuse myself and get 'config fatigue'?
There's a way, I'm sure but every time I've tried to either use `package.json` or a `webpack.config.js` accessed from anywhere but the intended location when I built it, it doesn't work either in part or at all.

Also, cherry picking out the contents of your `node_modules` folder can cause weird problems so I don't mess with it personally.

Just use:

> npm install [dependencies, dev-tools, and whatever you need]

and you should be sweet.

No need to have your optimal configs being passed around - just keep your npm install commands on hand to copy and paste at will.

Comment: Well done for your first answer! I've just tweaked it a little bit for the formatting and to remove a couple of comments that were going on a bit of a tangent, but other than that it's an interesting explanation. Make sure you take a look at what I changed so you can see what's expected on the site, so your questions get received well by others.